# The view count for questions should be incremented when the AI ask/answer tool uses their answers as sources

Tags: feature-request, views, overflow-ai

When AI was implemented, a user can ask it directly and an original question is not visited anymore. Yes, the original questions/answers was advertised below:
[image]

But:

- It would be nice to increase view counter by 1/3 in this case, because AI used 3 answers here, thus authors question/answer was visited.
- Instead of increase of original views SO can implement AI views. So users will see how often their information was used/advertised by AI
- In additional SO can count how many times users open original answers from AI page. This will measure how often the information provided by AI was not enough to find the answer
- In same way as "AI views" SO can implement "AI accepted answer". This will measure how often AI gives good answer. Yes, this is similar to "Did this solve your problem? Your feedback will help improve the results for other users.", but also will give some info to authors of original answers.

Comment: Is the view counter relevant for anything?

Comment: @BDL badges I suppose.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'd take that as a "no".

Comment: @BDL Yes, it shows how often provided information in a question/answer was related to user's problem, eg. we know that questions with `git` tag are visited/viewed really often, thus we can understand that `git` is popular tool. Similar, when this info is reused by AI we should not lose original views, we should know that info still was used.

Comment: @VLAZ See my comment above.

Comment: There's certainly value in views increasing for content that was in one way or another "used" by someone, but is a question showing up in search enough evidence it was used in a way worth increasing the view count at all?

Comment: @BDL The view count is used as part of the determination for Roomba (automatic deletion) of questions under certain circumstances. Zero-score, unclosed questions with no comments or answers will automatically delete under the '365 days' Roomba criterion if the view count is lower than the age of the question in days. Not likely useful in this situation, though, since the AI is presumably only looking for questions that have answers.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I haven't tested this but are you sure/do you have proof that the AI tool does not increase the view count of a question already when using it as a source? I'm not saying you are wrong, just making sure you are not requesting something that already exists.

Comment: "it shows how often provided information in a question/answer was related to user's problem" -- not really, it just counts how many times someone or something followed the link to that page. IIRC not even unique per-user at least in long-term.

Comment: @DanMašek Correct, you can generally increment the view count of a post yourself twice by visiting a page and refreshing, and then hard refreshing (e.g. Ctrl+F5). Of course, the name of the stat isn't 'unique people views', it's 'view count'. If I view a page 50 times a year, it should increase by 50 times, not one.

Comment: What AI are we even referring to here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's the OverflowAI/Search.

Answer (score 5):

Given all it takes for a Q&A pair to be featured in this list is for it to be loosely related to the search query you gave it, I don't think views should implicitly be incremented at all as a result of this.

Comment: But does it worth to implement: "used by AI" counter?

Comment: Internally, definitely. But I don't see any value in displaying it, It doesn't indicate anything useful. We shouldn't care how often it shows up as a search result, we should care how often the answer was deemed useful. I don't see how we can determine that from OverflowAI usage without the user directly going to each answer and determining which one was the source of the information that was actually helpful.

Comment: (which would directly increase the view-count on the ones that had a relevant enough title to justify visiting)

Comment: @KevinB It could be used in the stack exchange API maybe